# Shipping address data to be same as billing address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a billing address and shipping address fields. The shipping address fields are hidden unless a user clicks on a checkbox (stimulus) indicating "shipping address same as billing address?"

Using rails, how might one go about copying the text from the billing address to the shipping address when the checkbox is clicked? Ideally allowing this text to still be editable.

Comment: I've only played with Stimulus a little bit. I would guess that you can bind the two fields conditionally based on the check box you mentioned. Could you post the HTML of the area in question to get a better look at what you're trying to accomplish?